# How can I send array in form field with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, field, angular-ngmodel

I want insert dynamic fields into a form.

For example: 
I have a field list like:

```
<input type="text" name="names[]" class="name-1">
<input type="text" name="names[]"  class="name-2">
<input type="text" name="names[]"  class="name-1">
```

In jQuery I only need serializate all form and send it, like `$('#myForm').serialize().`

But, I don't know how can I do this in angular.

Somebody have some idea?

In angular i only know use the directive ng-mode and I can't do that: `ng-mode="myform.name[]"`

Comment: i believe that you are looking for ng-repet 

here is official ng-repet examle
http://plnkr.co/edit/uHDMWdO7gR3qBRmDotiU?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution and is to here:

```js
/* ------------------------------------------------------- 
* Source: http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically
* Author: Muhammed Shanid shanidkannur@gmail.com
**********Thank's very mush Muhammed **********
* Hacked By: Wilowayne De La Cruz wilo0087@gmail.com
---------------------------------------------------------*/

var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.fields = [{name: 'employed-name-1'}, {name: 'employed-name-2'}];
  
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.fields.length + 1;
    $scope.fields.push({'name':'employed-name-'+newItemNo});
  };
    
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.fields.length-1;
    $scope.fields.splice(lastItem);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="field in fields">     
      <input type="text" ng-model="field.value" name="" placeholder="Enter employe name">
     
      <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
       
   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ fields }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a data-model oriented framework. You can bind your model (ej: array of value) to view trhought ng-model and ng-repeat and so submit directly your binded model

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submitMyForm()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Input1</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input1" ng-model="input1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label ">Input2</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="input2" ng-model="input2"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Your angular controller could look like this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyController ($scope) {

    $scope.input1 = 'Pre-set value of input 1';
    $scope.input2 = 'Pre-set value of input 2';

    $submitMyForm = function()
    {
        console.log('input1 value: ' + $scope.input1);
        console.log('input2 value: ' + $scope.input2);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: This example no run to me couse i don't know how many field 'name' could I have.

Could be 4 or 7 fields, that depend to other variable.